# What is a better more testable way for Repository based on tenants

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have a repository that receives a data layer as parameter and a tenantID like this. (Code is simplefied)

```
 public class MyRepsitory{

        private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess;
        private readonly string _tenantID;

        public MyRepsitory(IDataAccess dataAccess, string tenantID)
        {
            _dataAccess = dataAccess;
            _tenantID = tenantID;

        }
}
}
```

This repository has also a method `GetClientsForTenantID` which is private and this is basically my point because every method relies on `GetClientsForTenantID` and this not ideal for unit testing because I cannot stub or mock `GetClientsForTenantID` in my current design. 
This is my current signature of the `GetClientsForTenantID` method at the moment. `private IEnumerable<string> GetClientsForTenant(string tenantID)` I want the repository to take care of it as internal behavior, that's why it is private. I do not want it as public member because then it is mutable for other developer and my api would not be reliable.  I could have made it virtual so that a Mocking Framework could proxy it, but that didn't feel right, either.

It would need to have some fakeClients injected only for testing, or something else...

This shows the issue I am having in code.
For example I cannot test my GetProducts() -Method

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(string someParameter){

        var clients = GetClientsForTenant(this._tenantId);

        //do some logic that needs to be tested 
    }
```

The other thought that I had was Injecting an `ITenantStore` basically a class that takes care of resolving the clients base on the tenantID. But this would also needs to get the IDataAccess passed in and would do things that should do the repository.

Like this:

```
TenantStore(IDataAccess dataAccess, string tenantID)

MyRepository(IDataAccess dataAccess, ITenantStore tenantStore)
```

does also not feel right because of the `IDataAccess` all over the place...

What would be you recommended way to solve this? Any hints tips?

EDIT:

Thanks for your comments the `GetClientsForTenant` is not on the `DataAccess` it's on the repository.

My Test would look like this:

```
var mockMockData = new Mock<IDataAccess>();

        mockMockData.Setup(x=>
            x.ExecuteQuery(It.IsAny<IDictionary<string,object>>(),It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(
               new List<Product>()
            )
            .Callback<IDictionary<string,object>>(
                (parameters,sql)=>{
                    passedInParameters = parameters;

            });
        _repository = new MyRepository(mockMockData.Object,"fakeUser");
var list = _repository.GetProducts();

// Assert the parameters that get's passed into the ExecuteQuery Method because there happens some logic.
```

Since the `GetClientsForTenant` is on Repository and private it does not help to Mock `IDataAccess`. It would just call DataAccess with different parameters but from the `MyRepository.GetClientsForTenant` method.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? the private method obviously gets the clients out of IDataAccess somehow. so mock that interface to only return what you want for the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 on zaitsman's comment. 
You seem to already have a nice seam in place that allows testing MyRepository in isolation.

If a) IDataAccess is an interface and b) your GetClientsForTenant method uses it internally, you can provide a fake IDataAccess that returns precooked fakeClients and you will be able to fully test MyRepository's logic without exposing any private methods.

Your gut feeling is right here. In general, you shouldn't have to expose privates in order to unit test something. That's why you should always focus on testing publicly visible *behavior* instead of tying your test code to an internal implementation, which you would do if you tried to fake out the GetClientsForTenant method. This will lead to brittle tests that will break every time you change some implementation detail (like calling a method other than GetClientsForTenant internally).

UPDATE: in your last edit you mention:
    "Since the GetClientsForTenant is on Repository and private it does not help     to Mock IDataAccess. It would just call DataAccess with different parameters but     from the MyRepository.GetClientsForTenant method."

Exactly, that is the entire point. Your tests shouldn't care about the internal implementation of your Repository. Whether or not GetClientsForTenant gets called is irrelevant. What might matter however is how your Repository communicates with its IDataAccess collaborator.